# Question on the proof of Theorem 7-1 in Spivak's Calculus

Tags: calculus

I have a question regarding the following proof in Spivak's Calculus. (I excerpted the post by Kepler 9 years ago)

> #### Theorem 7-1:
>
> If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f(a) < 0 < f(b)$, then there is some number $z$ in $[a,b]$ such that $f(x) = 0$.
>
> *Proof:*
> Define the set $A$ as follows:
>
> $$A = \{x : a \le x\le b, \mbox{ and } f \mbox{ is negative on the interval } [a,x] \}.$$
>
> Clearly $A \ne \emptyset$, since $a$ is in $A$; in fact, there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $A$ contains all points $x$ satisfying $a \le x < a + \delta$; this follows from Problem 6-16, since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f(a)<0$. Similarly, $b$ is an upper bound for $A$ and, in fact, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that all points $x$ satisfying $b-\delta < x \le b$ are upper bounds for $A$; this also follows from Problem 6-16, since $f(b) > 0$.
>
>      
> From these remarks it follows that $A$ has a least upper bound $\alpha$ and that $a < \alpha < b$. We now wish to show that $f(\alpha) = 0$, by eliminating the possibilities $f(\alpha) < 0$ and $f(\alpha) > 0$.
>
>      
> Suppose first that $f(\alpha) < 0$. By Theorem 6-3, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $f(x) < 0$ for $\alpha - \delta < x < \alpha + \delta$. Now there is some number $x_0$ in $A$ which satisfies $\alpha - \delta < x_0 < \alpha$ (because otherwise $\alpha$ would not be the *least* upper bound of $A$). This means that $f$ is negative on the whole interval $[a,x_0]$. But if $x_1$ is a number between $\alpha$ and $\alpha+\delta$, then $f$ is also negative on the whole interval $[x_0,x_1]$. Therefore $f$ is negative on the interval $[a,x_1]$, so $x_1$ is in $A$. But this contradicts the fact that $\alpha$ is an upper bound for $A$; our original assumption that $f(\alpha) < 0$ must be false.

$$\cdots$$

Is "Now there is some number $x_0$ in $A$ which satisfies $\alpha - \delta < x_0 < \alpha$" in the last paragraph above wrong? Should it be $\alpha - \delta < x_0 \le \alpha$? Although this won't affect the proof, I am just wondering whether my understanding of the least upper bound is correct or not. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For least upper bound we have strict inequlity from definition.

Comment: In Spivak, the definition is "A number $x$ is a least upper bound of $A$ if (1) $x$ is an upper bound  of $A$, and (2) if $y$ is an upper bound of $A$, then $x\le y$." It seems that there is no strict restriction in the definition.

Comment: It should be $x_0 \le \alpha$.

Comment: It's equivalent to following: (1) $\forall x \in A, x \leqslant \sup A$, (2) $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists x_0 \in A, \sup A - \epsilon < x_0$.

Comment: Put it together, it is exactly "$\alpha-\delta <x_0 \le \alpha$, where $\alpha=sup A$ and my $\delta $ is your $\epsilon$.

Comment: Understand. Strange, I thought you speak about left one. So you are interesting in right one, right? From Spivak we have, that $f(x)<0$ for $\alpha -\delta < x < \alpha +\delta $, so can we take $x_0=\alpha-\frac{\delta}{2}$?

Comment: The existence of $x_0$ is true, but not by definition of supremum. By definition of supremum, what we can say is that there exists a $\xi \in A$ such that $\alpha-\delta < \xi \leq \alpha$. But since $\xi\in A$, it means $[a,\xi] \subset A$. Hence, now we can choose an $x_0 \in (\alpha-\delta, \xi)$, and this will certainly also lie in $A$. So, indeed we have found an $x_0\in A$ such that $\alpha-\delta < x_0 < \alpha$. To sum up: the existence of $x_0$ is due to the definition of supremum, AND a simple property of $A$ (namely that if $\xi\in A$ then $[a,\xi]\subset A$)

Comment: but of course, this is completely unnecessary for the proof as you mention, and the weak inequality $\alpha-\delta < \xi \leq \alpha$ is enough to make the rest of the proof work

Comment: @peek-a-boo. It seems that everyone wants to save Spivak. If you are right, which I do agree, then Spivak's proof is either not complete or not rigorous.

Comment: Spivak's proof is definitely complete and rigorous, and the statement he made is correct, but it is correct not for the reason he stated; we also had to use additional information. Though I definitely agree that it is misleading (and unnecessary) to use $<$ rather than $\leq$ (but it could have also been a typo... who knows)... but still the proof is right.

Answer (score 1):

The only way for the inequality not to be strict is that $A=\{\alpha\}$. But this is impossible, since if  $f$ is negative on $[a,\alpha]$, then it is negative on $[a,\alpha-\delta]$ for $\delta>0$. And $\alpha>a$ because $f$ is continuous.

In summary, the strict inequality is fine because of the context. It's not because of the definition of least upper bound.

Comment: Thanks. My question is "Is Spivak's argument wrong based on the definition of the least upper bound?" Or at least his argument is not rigorous or not complete since $\alpha-\delta < x_0\le \alpha$ will do the job as well.

Comment: Spivak's way is the usual way to use the definition of LUB. And his argument is both rigorous and complete, since $x_0$ as he writes does exist. It's true that in this case the argument also works if $x_0=\alpha$, but nothing is gained by that.

Comment: I don't agree that "$x_0$ as he writes does exist" since the definition is just not that..It is easy to give a counter example based on the definition that $x_0$ is not necessarily strictly less than $sup A$.